# creating dir with mkdir in debian

Tags: debian, mkdir, gnome-terminal

I am trying to create a directory using mkdir in Debian but the problem is that the directory is created in the root directory. The problem comes trying to install OpenFOAM and I suspect that it is because "$" is used to create it.

Following the instructions in the OpenFOAM web site, it says to create a folder

`$HOME/OpenFOAM/user-2.2.1`

and then, to create within a folder called "run" using:

`mkdir -p /FOAM_RUN`

the problem is that the final directory (run) should have the following form:

`/home/OpenFOAM/user-2.2.1/run`

but using Debian I cannot create a dir with "sudo", so I have to do it as root and when I go inside the directory /home/OpenFOAM/user-2.2.1 and I do mkdir -p /FOAM_RUN , then the created folder is:

`/root/OpenFOAM/root-2.2.1/run`

and I need it to be created in the /home directory and not in the /root directory. I had created the folder just using

`mkdir -p /home/OpenFOAM/user-2.2.1/run`

but when I try to execute the OpenFOAM orders it doesn't work.

My questions are:

Why should `mkdir $FOAM_RUN` create the run directory and if I do it just as "mkdir run", it doesn't work?

Why is the "$" symbol there when I use mkdir? I was searching for it and (for example) the mkdir manual says nothing about it.

Excuse me, I am not an expert in Linux.

Comment: please correct the typos in your question. e.g. `/FOAM_RUN` is a fundamentally different folder than `$FOAM_RUN`, but you seem to use them interchangibly

Comment: `mkdir -p /FOAM_RUN` says to create a directory `FOAM_RUN` in the root directory. The command `mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN` says to examine the environment variable `FOAM_RUN` and use its value as the name of the directory to create. You can examine environment variables with `set` and assign `FOAM_RUN=/path/to/wherever`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The instructions](http://www.openfoam.org/download/ubuntu.php) are fairly straightforward, but you seem to have missed one of the notes. To reiterate a point they are making, you need to `source ~/.bashrc` after updating it.  Then if you `echo "$FOAM_RUN"` you should see that this variable is now set to something like `/home/luser/OpenFOAM/luser-2.2.1/run`.

If you prefer to override it by hand, and assuming your user name is `luser` and your OpenFOAM version is 2.2.1, do this:

```
FOAM_RUN=$HOME/OpenFOAM/$USER-2.2.1/run
mkdir -p "$FOAM_RUN" # Note pedantic quoting
```

But if your `.bashrc` contains the code they instruct you to add, this should not be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

there is no reason why you cannot use `sudo` on Debian.
if you don't have `sudo` installed, just install it, using something like the following (as root)

```
aptitude install sudo
```

after that, you have to configure it, so that your `user` can use the command.
the easiest way to do so, is to run the following (as root):

```
adduser USER sudo
```

you have to replace USER by the user-id you want to allow using `sudo`.
then you have to make log-in *again* as this user (if the user is already logged in, log it out)